# Android Gradle - Assertion Error

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to do a Gradle Sync, I get an error that says the following:

> 21:24:11 AssertionError:
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectComponent@8e8dc05
>   22:13:53 AssertionError: null

And when I view the error in detail, I get this **Stack Trace**:

> null java.lang.AssertionError     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.attemptToUpdateGradleVersionInWrapper(PreSyncChecks.java:174)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.ensureCorrectGradleSettings(PreSyncChecks.java:72)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.PreSyncChecks.canSync(PreSyncChecks.java:53)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doImport(GradleProjectImporter.java:430)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.doRequestSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:219)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.access$000(GradleProjectImporter.java:77)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter$2.run(GradleProjectImporter.java:184)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.invokeLaterIfProjectAlive(AppUIUtil.java:77)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.GradleProjectImporter.requestProjectSync(GradleProjectImporter.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.actions.SyncProjectAction.actionPerformed(SyncProjectAction.java:43)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:170)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:133)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:313)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)     at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IntelliJ and Android Gradle plugin greater than 0.14 you might have this error. I filed a bug for that:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134118

Star the issue, vote it up and they might take a closer look :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
```

in build.gradle file

Comment: Could you explain why should it be downgrade? It's supposed to work with new version, I am right?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bad gradle version set in your build.gradle.

try changing your gradle build version in your gradle dependencies like below

```
dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
}
```